# Slide div out relative to an element on the page

Tags: jquery, css, html

This question covered how to slide a div out and that works fine now.

But - and I should have seen this coming - the div slides out at a position relative to the upper-left of the page. I have my body tag set to 1200px (changing that is not an option for the layout I am required to have). I need it to be positioned such that the right hand edge of the flyout div is right on the left edge of the "View TDM Status" cell that was clicked on.

So, here is a sample of the table with the div slid out.

[image: Table with Flyout div showing]

As you can see, the div is slightly to the right of where I want it. I was developing on a different computer with a different screen resolution, and the above screenshot is on a different screen resolution.

So, how can I get the div's right hand edge to be on the left hand edge of the cell that was clicked in, after the div is done sliding out?

Code samples:

HTML:
This is a row from the table with the cell that the user clicks on:

```
<div id="siteDataRow-5" class="rowDataSites divRow">
    <div class="cellDataEditDelBtns divCell userSitesCol1">
        <button class="btnDeleteSite buttonStyle">Delete</button>
        <button class="btnEditSite buttonStyle">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cellDataSiteName divCell userSitesCol2">
        <label class="lblSiteName">Oskaloosa</label>
    </div>
    <div  class="cellDataServerLoc divCell userSitesCol3">
        <label class="lblSiteServerLoc">888.888.888.888</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cellDataSolCtrNum divCell userSitesCol4">
        <label class="lblSiteSolCtr">SQL123</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cellDataPM divCell userSitesCol5">
        <label class="lblSitePm">John Smith</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cellDataStatusNotes divCell userSitesCol6">
        <label class="lblSiteNotes">Hopefully this will have formatted text in it.</label><br>
        <br>
        <label class="lblLnkAddEditNotes mouseHand">Add/Edit Notes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="cellDataViewTdmStatus divCell userSitesCol7">
        <label class="lblViewTdmStatus mouseHand">View<br>TDM<br>Status</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The user clicks on the label in the last cell to make the div slide out.

This is the div that slides out:

```
<div id="tblTdmStatusData" class="divTbl">
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divCell containerCell">
            <div class="divTbl subTbl">
                <div class="divRow">
                    <div id="statusSuApTdm" class="divCell tdmCell firstCell">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusSuArTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusSuClinTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Clin</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusSuGlTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">GL</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusSuPayTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Pay</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell containerCell">
            <div class="divTbl subTbl">
                <div class="divRow">
                    <div id="statusParApTdm" class="divCell tdmCell firstCell">
                        <a href="#">AP</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusParArTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">AR</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusParClinTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Clin</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusParGlTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">GL</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusParPayTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Pay</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="divCell containerCell">
            <div class="divTbl">
                <div class="divRow">
                    <div id="statusActApTdm" class="divCell tdmCell firstCell">
                        <a href="#">AP</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusActArTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">AR</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusActClinTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Clin</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusActGlTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">GL</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="statusActPayTdm" class="divCell tdmCell">
                        <a href="#">Pay</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:
Here's the working js that slides the div out:

```
$('.lblViewTdmStatus').click(function() {
    // Get the position of the label that was clicked on
    var position = $(this).position(),
        left = position.left,
        top = position.top,
        divLeft = position.left - 588,
        divTop = position.top - 32;
    //console.log('Left position: ' + divLeft + ' Top position: ' + divTop);

    // Position the div
    $('#tdmStatus').css('top',divTop).css('left',divLeft);

    // Slide the div out
    $('#tdmStatus').toggle('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
});
```

Comment: I know they say a picture is worth a thousand words, but when it comes to issues with code, it's really not worth anything.

Comment: Also, since you say "my body tag", I must ask, where did you learn HTML? A tag is not the same as an element!

Comment: I agree with @adeneo that you need to post your code.

Comment: Sorry - you're right - I'll do that shortly

Comment: Could the div just be a dialog with the data and a "close" button? Can you make the div less wide?

Comment: @TimSPQR: well, yeah - I could, but where would be the challenge in that? :) No, I'd really like to get this to work - that is if it's not going to take some serious jumping through hoops to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to explain without a real example.

To get it at the left edge of the label I would add position: relative; to the wrapper-container (which contains all rows) and would add position: absolute; to the sliding element. Then calculate or know (if it's fix) the width of the clicked label-cell and change your javascript this way:

```
...
// Position the div
    $('#tdmStatus').css('top',divTop).css('right', labelWidth);
...
```

I'm not sure if this would work as you want it to. It would be easier to help if you create a fiddle or send a link to the real side.

Comment: Thanks, MichaB. That did the trick! I just added the positions you suggested and added margin settings to move it slightly. Tested on three different computers with three different resolutions, including resizing the browser - works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help, but I put together a boring fiddle that might be a starting point for discussion. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w2XYv/). (just click on the red bar to start the process).

Here's the CSS:

```
.sliderdiv {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

So if you float the sliding div left, then it will be as narrow as its contents.

Then, if it's still bumping the right-hand column of interest, I guess you'll either have to move it to the right, or squeeze the contents a bit.